# Using NPM module in Backbone with RequireJS

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, npm, requirejs, bower

Hejsa,
I'm writing a webapp, which consists of a Node backend (Express server), which serves a Backbone app to the clients.
The Backbone app uses RequireJS to load the modules used.
I would like to use Ag-grid clientside, which can be included as an NPM module.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-getting-started/index.php

How can I reference this NPM module from Backbone?

**Project structure**

`./node_modules
./src/package.json
./src/app (Node backend + Express server)
./src/public
./src/public/main.coffee (contains requireJs config)
./src/public/scripts (Backbone views, models, etc)`

**main.coffee**

```
require.config
    baseUrl: '../scripts/'
    paths:
        jquery: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min'
        jqueryui: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min'
        underscore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min'
        ...
```

I would like to include the ag-grid NPM module here, but without having to reference the very top `./node_modules` folder as `../../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid` (*didn't count the levels..*).
Also, I'd like if possible to avoid a second package.js, and a secondary `npm install`

Any help related specifically to this project structure?
Secondarily, is there any better way to structure such a project? (Node backend serving a Backbone webapp)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it and using a relative path all the way to the `node_modules` directory is the way to go.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "ag-grid": "../../../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid",
        "backbone": "../../../node_modules/backbone/backbone"
    }
});

define(["backbone", "ag-grid"], function(Backbone, agGrid) {
    // whatever
});
```

You could also use `npm` for all the dependencies and bundle an optimized version of your app using the [RequireJS optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) (`r.js`).

Personally, I use `npm` for the development of the project and for server-side (node) dependencies. For my Backbone app, I use [Bower](https://bower.io/) as it's specialized in front-end dependencies management.

I have a `.bowerrc` file that tells bower where to install the dependencies:

```
{
    "directory": "src/lib",
}
```

And a Gulp task which calls `bower install`:

```
var bower = require("bower"),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true }),
    gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    return bower.commands.install()
        .on('log', function(data) {
            $.util.log('bower', $.util.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
        });
});
```

this task is called automatically after `npm install` with a npm hook:

```
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "postinstall": "gulp install"
}
```

Take a look at [simplified-js-project](https://github.com/emileber/simplified-js-project), a sample project which shows my development tools around a Backbone and RequireJs project.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the matter, Emile :)
Good to hear that option 1 is viable.
Regarding your second suggestion, I'm not familiar with Bower, so let's see if I understood you correctly:
- In my `package.json`, I would define a `postinstall` script, which executes the `gulp install` task of my build system.
- This task would require bower, and execute the `bower` Gulp task. The point of this task is to get the packages I'm interested in, bundle them and save them in a place (such as `./build/public/scripts/vendor`) where I can easily retrieve them via RequireJS, clientside?

Comment: if so, I will look into Bower docs to see how to define what packages I'm interested in having bundled together and made available to RequireJS.
On a separate note: If I was to refactor the whole project, and start over, would anyone have any pointer on how to improve the structure / tech stack being used?

Comment: @jj-lucas Bower is almost a clone of npm, it only install dependencies to a specified folder, according to a `bower.json` file. The gulp task is optional and you could just use bower directly: `"postinstall": "bower install"`. You can place your bower dependencies inside an easy to access directory, close to your RequireJs project. Than, when ready, you can use `r.js` to bundle and minimize your app and all the dependencies used in require.

Comment: @jj-lucas I added a link to [simplified-js-project](https://github.com/emileber/simplified-js-project) in my answer which should help.

Comment: fantastic! that repo is gonna be extremely useful as a reference